# Anybody know of any tools for tailing a users path through the logs please?

Tags: logs

Users of our websites normally come to us via other web based applications our company provides. All these applications are on different servers so we normally end up tailing several logs on different servers in order to follow the users journey as he navigates between applications.

Someone, somewhere has mentioned a tool which effectively tails a users journey in the logs across different servers but I can't remember for the life of me what it is.

Does this sound familiar to anyone please?

I'm sure the name was something like "Log Pather", "Path Logger" or something like that. Searching has proved fruitless for me.

Comment: Doesn't sound familiar - have just used a shell script for this purpose previously. Could you provide a bit more info about the environments? E.g. O/S, webservers, etc?

Comment: Cheers Anna. It was a tool someone mentioned in passing - he was very vague!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do, one of these might be what you're looking for.  Or, just searching for any combination of these will result in a number of "software comparision" articles that might list the one you're looking for:

- commercial: [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com)  ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splunk)), [LogScape](http://www.liquidlabs.com/main/)
- [Logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/)
- [Swatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/)
- [Octopussy](http://www.octopussy.pm/dokuwiki/doku.php)

Comparisons, lists:

- [log management tools](http://theagileadmin.com/2010/06/14/log-management-tools/)
- "[build your own splunk](http://devopsangle.com/2012/06/18/build-your-own-splunk-like-central-log-management-tool-with-open-source-software/)"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking of LogParser?
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659

It allows you to conduct SQL-style queries through a bunch of text-based log files and many other input sources.